# Why is Okosan the only one without a Human representation?

Tags: hatoful-boyfriend

In *Hatoful Boyfriend*, Okosan is the only <s>person</s> bird to not receive a human drawing.

Why is that?

[image]

whereas every other character:

[image]
[image]
[image][image][image][image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to Moa on Saturday Hatoful Boyfriend panel Q&A with Moa and Damurushi @ AOD 2016,

> The reason Okosan doesn't have a human portrait is because the real-life Okosan is family to Moa, and attaching her own "human" image to him would feel strange.
>
> ([Source](https://militarypenguin.dreamwidth.org/39562.html))